# How to check test coverage for changed files using nyc and mocha?

Tags: git, mocha.js, code-coverage, nyc

I'm currently getting my test coverage with `nyc` and `mocha` through something along this:

```
nyc mocha --recursive $(find src -name '*.spec.ts')
```

I run this on my CI. However, this runs through all my test files. I would like to verify the test coverage threshold only for the files that are changed in the current branch compared to the master branch.

I have looked around for a solution to this and the closest I could find is to use `git diff --name-only` to get the files that were changed. But I'm still not sure how I can use `git diff` in combination with `nyc` and `mocha` to achieve what I want.

How can I verify and check the test coverage meeting its threshold in my CI for only the changed files using `nyc` and `mocha`?